# How would I take the sum of different paths in a graph with Haskell

Tags: haskell, graph, functional-programming

> ### Problem
>
> `relatedQuestions` calculates the question with the shortest reading
>   time. Given the number of questions, an array of each questions
>   reading time, and and array of edges between questions.
>
> ```
> questions = 5
> readingTimes = [2, 1, 13, 1, 12]
> edges = [[3,0], [3,2], [4,1], [3,1]]
>
> answer: 3
> ```
>
> To calculate the "shortest reading time" of a question you need to
>   take the sum of reading times of each path a child node makes and divide it by the number of direct children the question has *(question
>   being the current node)*. Then add this number to the current
>   questions reading time.
>
> Ex using inputs above:
>
> ```
>       (paths)
>  current question          children       #direct    #readingTime
>  0 -> 3 -> 1 -> 4      2   + (1 + 1 + 12) / 1        = 30 
>         -> 2               + (1 + 13)     / 1          
>
>  1 -> 4                 1  + (12)         / 1        = 13
>
>  2 -> 3 -> 0           13  + (1 + 2)      / 1        = 28
>         -> 1 -> 4          + (1 + 12)     / 1
>
>  3 -> 0                 1  + (2)          / 3        = 10.3 
>    -> 1 -> 4               + (1 + 12)     / 3
>    -> 2                    + (13)         / 3
> ```

### Issue and Request

My code works for the given test cases below, but it may fail for others. My code depends on Data.Graph's reachable to get all nodes that a current node can reach and sum all its children divided by the total direct children, but I need to divide each individual child nodes tree sum by the total direct children. So what I'm doing is taking the sum of all paths and dividing by the number of direct children when I should be dividing each path sum.

I want to use Data.Graph's component function to fold the tree accordingly and accumulate the smallest sum. I was having issues with working on a `Forest Vertex` type, but using `sequence` I got a type of `Tree [Vertex]` making it a bit easier for me to work with regardless I have not been able to wrap my mind around the recursion/traversing necessary.

```
 *Main> :t graph1
 graph1 :: Graph
 *Main> :t components graph1
 components graph1 :: Forest Vertex
 *Main> :t sequence . components $ graph1
 sequence . components $ graph1 :: Tree [Vertex]
 *Main> sequence . components $ graph1
 Node {rootLabel = [0], subForest = [Node {rootLabel = [3], subForest= [Node {rootLabel = [2], subForest = []},Node {rootLabel = [1], subForest = [Node {rootLabel = [4], subForest = []}]}]}]}
```

I'd really appreciate some help on either optimizing my current code to be a full solution or explanations on how I can use `Data.Graph`'s component function to fold/traverse a `[Forest Vertex]`.

```
import Data.Graph
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Vector as V

relatedQuestions :: Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]] -> Int
relatedQuestions n t edges = snd smallest
     where 
           smallest = minimum [(price (snd q) (related (snd q) edges) (fst q) , snd q) | q <- zip t (vertices graph)] 
           price q r i = (fromIntegral (reach q) / fromIntegral r) + fromIntegral i
           reach q = V.sum . V.tail $ V.fromList [ (V.fromList t) V.! x | x <- reachable graph q]
           graph = createGraph n createEdges
           createEdges = concat [permutations x | x <- edges] -- makes sure edge [1,0] has edge [0,1]


-- | helper functions 

-- | number of children at node   
related :: Int -> [[Int]] -> Int
related n = length . filter (==n) . concat

createGraph :: Int -> [[Int]] -> Graph
createGraph e = buildG (0, e-1) . map (\[x,y] -> (x,y))
```

### Test Cases

```
-- | test cases 
main :: IO ()
main = hspec $ do
   describe "relatedQuestions" $ do 
         it "test case 1" $ do 
       relatedQuestions n1 t1 edges1 `shouldBe` (3 :: Int)  
         it "test case 2" $ do 
       relatedQuestions n2 t2 edges2 `shouldBe` (4 :: Int)  
         it "test case 3" $ do 
       relatedQuestions n3 t3 edges3 `shouldBe` (2 :: Int)  

n1 :: Int   
n1 =  5

t1 :: [Int]
t1 = [2, 1, 13, 1, 12]

edges1 :: [[Int]]
edges1 = [[3,0], [3,2], [4,1], [3,1]]

n2 :: Int
n2 = 5

t2 :: [Int]
t2 = [3, 11, 3, 18, 3]

edges2 :: [[Int]]
edges2 = [[3,1], [4,2], [0,3], [4,1]]

n3 :: Int
n3 = 10

t3 :: [Int]
t3 = [9, 2, 7, 14, 4, 26, 21, 18, 39, 33]

edges3 :: [[Int]]
edges3 = [[2,7], [0,9], [3,5], [4,7], [0,2], [8,5], [3,6], [2,1], [5,0]]
```

Comment: "...because I get type errors with components type Forest Vertex vs Tree Int's." - include this code and the type error you get.

Comment: I still haven't been able to write any code, but I included what I have been looking at so far.